# weblogic jms connection factory not found

Tags: weblogic11g

I have a an admin and a managed server. A JMS server is targeting the admin server. The JMS Module which contains the Queue and the Connection Factory is targetting both the admin and the managed server.
When my application is deployed on the admin server everything works. But when is deployed on the managed server i get the following excpetion

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'CONNECTION_F'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'CONNECTION_F'

I can see from the JNDI tree of the managed that CONNECTION_F is not present...
Am I missing something? Something wrong configured on the domain?

I am using Weblogic 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Please configure your JMS server on the managed server too.

Comment: I do not mean target your existing JMS server. I mean creating a new JMS server and target it to your managed server.